# How to get DOM element from Kendo view model?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I would like to know if it's possible to get the DOM element from a kendo mvvm.

My input is defined like :

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" data-bind="value: model.Name" />
```

at some point I'm setting the value in javascript like :

```
myViewModel.set("model.Name", "John Doe");
```

This sets the value inside the bound element automatically, but after setting that value I would like to change something on the DOM element that just got updated. Like :

```
myViewModel.getElement("model.Name").className = "MyClass;
```

It seems kendo doesn't have that kind of function. The opposite is possible tho with `kendoBindingTarget`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way of doing this. I've worked with Kendo a lot (but would prefer not to again) and dug through the mvvm logic a bit, but I couldn't find the internal method they use within my patience. If you're willing to put more time into it, you can probably find it, but it's questionable if it's worth the effort. While you might not like this input, personally I think there are better alternatives than Kendo for mvvm for the reason demonstrated by your question: nonstandard behavior is often a pain to implement with Kendo.

Comment: What are other alternatives besides kendo then?

Comment: As with anything, [Google will help you plentily](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+mvvm). Personally I prefer [Rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/), but that's a matter of both personal preference and what other libraries you work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a [custom binding](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom) where on refresh (which is the set) I have access to the element :

html

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" data-bind="customValue: model.Name" />
```

js

```
kendo.data.binders.customValue= kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function(element, bindings, options) {
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);

        var that = this;
        $(that.element).on("change", function() {
            that.change();
        });
    },
    refresh: function() {
        var that = this,
            value = that.bindings["customValue"].get();

        $(that.element).val(value).addClass('MyClass'); //<======that.element========
    },
    change: function() {
        var value = this.element.value;
        this.bindings["customValue"].set(value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the element of a widget like this:

```
var myElement = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow").element;
```

You'll just need to use the right widget name for whatever your widget is. [According to the documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/widgets/wrapper-element) this will return it as a jQuery object.

Comment: I agree with this simple work arround, Kendo MVVM does not have reverse functionality of kendoBindingTarget. Hence to access DOM from viewmodel, we can simply add id or class to the DOM element and get the widget by it's id or class. In my case I have to access the text of DropDownList after a template is binded to a model. This is simple enough without making custom binding.